# Count of Values

Tags: python, csv, count

I need to count the number of occurrences in a row from a csv file.  I am using a file that is counting how many crimes were committed in a particular month by beat.  There are 20 beats [1A,1B,1C....] and so forth.  I have already used this setup to count integers in a range but for some reason I am hung up trying to get it to calculate if it contains a number and letter.  Any suggestions?

```
import csv
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "crime.csv"

with open(filename) as file:
    data_from_file = csv.reader(file)
    header_row = next(data_from_file)
    
    ucr_ncic_code = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for row in data_from_file:
        crime = int(float(row[6]))
        if crime in range(0,999):
            ucr_ncic_code[0] = ucr_ncic_code[0] +1
        elif crime in range(1000,1999):
            ucr_ncic_code[1] = ucr_ncic_code[1] +1
        elif crime in range(2000,2999):
            ucr_ncic_code[2] = ucr_ncic_code[2] +1
        elif crime in range(3000,3999):
            ucr_ncic_code[3] = ucr_ncic_code[3] +1
        elif crime in range(4000,4999):
            ucr_ncic_code[4] = ucr_ncic_code[4] +1
        elif crime in range(5000,5999):
            ucr_ncic_code[5] = ucr_ncic_code[5] +1
        elif crime in range(6000,6999):
            ucr_ncic_code[6] = ucr_ncic_code[6] +1
        elif crime in range(7000,7999):
            ucr_ncic_code[7] = ucr_ncic_code[7] +1
        elif crime in range(8000,8999):
            ucr_ncic_code[8] = ucr_ncic_code[8] +1

with open(filename) as file:
    data_from_file = csv.reader(file)
    header_row = next(data_from_file)
        
    district = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for row in data_from_file:
        D = int(float(row[2]))
        if D in range(2):
            district[0] = district[0] +1
        elif D in range(3):
            district[1] = district[1] +1
        elif D in range(4):
            district[2] = district[2] +1
        elif D in range(5):
            district[3] = district[3] +1
        elif D in range(6):
            district[4] = district[4] +1
        elif D in range(7):
            district[5] = district[5] +1
        
with open(filename) as file:
    data_from_file = csv.reader(file)
    header_row = next(data_from_file) 
       
    beat = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for row in data_from_file:
        B = str(row[3])
        if B == "1A":
            beat[0] = beat[0] +1
        elif B in range(3):
            beat[1] = beat[1] +1
        elif B in range(4):
            beat[2] = beat[2] +1
        elif B in range(5):
            beat[3] = beat[3] +1
        elif B in range(6):
            beat[4] = beat[4] +1
        elif B in range(7):
            beat[5] = beat[5] +1       

def option1():
    print("\nNCIC Codes")
    print("    0-999:",ucr_ncic_code[0])
    print("1000-1999:",ucr_ncic_code[1])
    print("2000-2999:",ucr_ncic_code[2])
    print("3000-3999:",ucr_ncic_code[3])
    print("4000-4999:",ucr_ncic_code[4])
    print("5000-5999:",ucr_ncic_code[5])
    print("6000-6999:",ucr_ncic_code[6])
    print("7000-7999:",ucr_ncic_code[7])
    print("8000-8999:",ucr_ncic_code[8])
    print("\nDistricts")
    print("District 1:",district[0])
    print("District 2:",district[1])
    print("District 3:",district[2])
    print("District 4:",district[3])
    print("District 5:",district[4])
    print("District 6:",district[5])
    print("\nBeats")
    print("Beat 1A:",beat[0])
    


def main():
    cont = "y"
    
    while(cont =="y"):
        print("\n\t\tMENU")
        print("1: Display Crime Report Data")
        print("2: Crime Statistics by Specific Beat")
        print("3: Compare Beat Statistics")
        print("4: Quit")
        print("\nSelect an option above:")
        user_input = input("---> ")

        if (user_input == "1"):
            option1()
            #elif (user_input == "2"):
           
        elif (user_input == "4"):
            break
            

main()
```

Comment: If you print out `row`, is its contents what you expected?

Comment: The result is 0 and there are hundreds of results.

Comment: So, that at least explains why the test always fails. If you get to see other data than there is in that file you are reading, there must be something wrong with your read-a-file code.

Comment: Still extremely new; I don't understand what you mean that it fails even though it results in 0.  I have upload all of my code I have to show in case something else I have might be causing the issue.  I tried uploading my csv but I don't see a way to do that either.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; the csv I was given had extra spaces after the beat 1A so I had to rstrip that data.